# Unhashable type: 'Indirect Object' in PyPDF2?

Tags: python, pypdf

I've used PyPDF2 successfully with other PDF's without a hitch but when trying to work with this current one I can't retrieve the pages without getting this error. Specifically, this is on the mergePage method. It must be something specific with the PDF because when I try another one (different structure) it works correctly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Combine /ProcSet sets.
    newResources[NameObject("/ProcSet")] = ArrayObject(
        frozenset(originalResources.get("/ProcSet", ArrayObject()).getObject()).union(
            frozenset(page2Resources.get("/ProcSet", ArrayObject()).getObject())
        )
    )
```

Just an update for anyone experiencing the same problem. Removing the code above in pdf.py inside the PyPDF2 folder will allow you to bypass this issue. I'm not sure what negative implications removing this code will have, but I can confirm it fixes my original issue.